# How to select password that start symbol itself in this case the '%' itself?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

`SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE password LIKE '%%';`

This statement is incorrect but is there a way to find password that start with `'%','''','!',etc.`

I am Trying to find password that start with any symbol in front ? How can I do that ?

Example Password :`%$rk3d+R&`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that you should *not* be storing clear text passwords in your customers table.  Doing so exposes your site to significant risk, if someone ever finds a way to read your database table.  Instead, you should *always* store an irreversible hash of the password in the customers table.  Then, for user authentication, hash a user's input password and compare against the table.

That being said, the `%` has a special meaning when used inside a `LIKE` expression, and it means any number of characters.  You may escape it via a backslash in this case to mean a literal `%` symbol:

```sql
SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE password LIKE '\%%';
```

More generally, to find customers having passwords starting with *any* symbol, use `REGEXP`:

```sql
SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE password REGEXP '^[@#$%^&*]';
```

Comment: I think they need `%\%` not `\%%`

Comment: @Āchahms That's not what the OP actually says.  It is asking for password starting with `%`, not containing `%` somewhere in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

- You need to escape the special character here like below.

```
SELECT * FROM test where password like '\%%';
```

[Demo DBFiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/aKhrhrnWhECZyEhqt7uFSb/0)